# Como criar um menu de abas, com JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, menu

Tenho um menu que caso o usuário selecione a opção ele vai mudando, etc! O problema é que ele deixa todos os outros programas abertos quando acessa um.

Menu:

```
<body onLoad="AlternarAbas('td_usua','div_usua')">
<table width="945" height="50"  align="left" valign="top" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" border="0" style="border-left: 1px solid #000000;" >
   <tr>
    <td height="20" width="50" class="menu" id="td_usua" onClick="AlternarAbas('td_usua','div_usua')">Usuario</td>
    <td height="20" width="50" class="menu" id="td_empr" onClick="AlternarAbas('td_empr','div_empr')">Empresa</td>
    <td height="20" width="50" class="menu" id="td_nota" onClick="AlternarAbas('td_nota','div_nota')">Nota Fiscal</td>
    <td height="20" width="50" class="menu" id="td_soft" onClick="AlternarAbas('td_soft','div_soft')">Software</td>
  </tr>
```

AlternarAbas:

```
function AlternarAbas(menu,conteudo)
{
  for (i=0;i<arAbas.length;i++)
  {
   m = document.getElementById(arAbas[i].menu);
   m.className = 'menu';
   c = document.getElementById(arAbas[i].conteudo)
   c.style.display = 'none';
  }
  m = document.getElementById(menu)
  m.className = 'menu-sel';
  c = document.getElementById(conteudo)
  c.style.display = '';
}
```

arAbas:

```
var arAbas = new Array();
arAbas[0] = new stAba('td_usua','div_usua');
arAbas[1] = new stAba('td_empr','div_empr');
arAbas[2] = new stAba('td_nota','div_nota');
arAbas[3] = new stAba('td_soft','div_soft');
```

stAba:

```
function stAba(menu,conteudo)
{
  this.menu = menu;
  this.conteudo = conteudo;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s65pQ/3/)

Assim, pensei em utilizar o `switch` ou `(if..else)` para mudar o modo de seleção. Ou seja, só ira abrir determinada área quando ela for acessada. Mas não tenho ideia de como implementar .. Alguma sugestão ou dica?

---

Mesmo postando uma resposta, gostaria de saber pelo menos se a uma maneira de fazer utilizando o `switch` ou o `(if..else)`!

Comment: Não entendi :( @Felipe - crie um jsfiddle

Comment: Legal @Felipe, mas não entendi assim.. oque é pra fazer.. Vc quer que quando clique ela fique ativa? Alguma coisa assim?

Comment: @JeffersonAlison, o meu problema é que quando eu seleciono uma aba, ele traz o conteúdo das demais abas juntos .. ou seja, eles permanecem abertos! Eu desejo que quando selecionar uma aba, só ela tenha conteúdo e as demais permaneçam em branco!

Answer (score 4):

O teu código de *JavaScript* para que possam ser chamado no evento `onload` da tag `BODY`, deverá estar presente dentro da secção `<head></head>` da tua página:

[Exemplo a Funcionar no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/R8BTs/)

```html
...
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript">
     function stAba(menu,conteudo) {
       this.menu = menu;
       this.conteudo = conteudo;
     }

     var arAbas = new Array();
     arAbas[0] = new stAba('td_usua','div_usua');
     arAbas[1] = new stAba('td_empr','div_empr');
     arAbas[2] = new stAba('td_nota','div_nota');
     arAbas[3] = new stAba('td_soft','div_soft');   

     function AlternarAbas(menu,conteudo) {
      for (i=0;i<arAbas.length;i++)
      {
       m = document.getElementById(arAbas[i].menu);
       m.className = 'menu';
       c = document.getElementById(arAbas[i].conteudo)
       c.style.display = 'none';
      }
      m = document.getElementById(menu)
      m.className = 'menu-sel';
      c = document.getElementById(conteudo)
      c.style.display = '';
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="AlternarAbas('td_usua', 'div_usua', 'form_usua')">
 ...
```

---

### Tudo correcto mas não funciona

Se tens a tag de `script` presente na secção `head` da tua página e mesmo assim o código não é executado em condições conforme pode ser visto no link em cima para o [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/R8BTs/), então o provável é existir um erro de JavaScript na página cujo mesmo está a levar o navegador a interromper a execução de *scripts*.

Quando isto acontece, determinadas coisas controladas por JavaScript não se verificam na página.

No teu caso em particular, como a tua função `AlternarAbas` está responsável por esconder todas as abas e activar apenas uma, se a execução de JavaScript é interrompida antes desta função ser executada, ficas com todas as abas visíveis.

#### Solução

Deverás fazer uso do *Inspector* do teu navegador para observar os erros que aparecem na consola de forma a identificar e resolver os mesmos.

### Documentação

Como pode ser lido na [MDN - window.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onload):

> The load event fires at the end of the document loading process. At this point, all of the objects in the document are in the DOM, and all the images and sub-frames have finished loading.

Que traduzido:

> O evento de carregamento dispara no final do processo de carregamento do documento. Neste ponto, todos os objectos no documento estão no DOM, e todas as imagens e sub-frames terminaram de ser carregadas.

Isto diz-nos que a tua função `AlternarAbas` vai ser chamada após a leitura do documento, se o mesmo contiver erros a função não é executada, levando ao problema que enfrentas.

---

### JSFiddle

Para que este tipo de cenários possa ser testado no JSFiddle, é preciso escolher as duas opções em baixo indicadas:

1. Indicar que a tab de javascript deve ficar no `<head>`;
2. Preencher o campo para a tag `body` ao invés de colocar no editor.

[image: Indicar JavaScript para head] [image: Preencher o HTML para a tag body]

Comment: Bem @Zuul, ele já se encontra dentro da secção `<head></head>`, eu só  não coloquei no exemplo!

Comment: @Felipe Como podes ver pelo JSFiddle que criei, o teu código está a funcionar em condições. Complementei a pergunta com informação adicionar sobre o JavaScript poder estar a ser interrompido por um erro antes desse teu código das Abas.

Answer (score 1):

Olá,

Sei que já responderam utilizando Javascript puro, mas que tal essa solução em jQuery?

http://jsfiddle.net/vrcca/a8yM7/

Abs!